# I can't get my var counts right

Tags: javascript

i cant get my var counts to keep track of the count in the if statement can anyone help me

```
 Laser.prototype.update = function () {
    //.3
    this.rot += .3
    this.pos.add(this.dir.clone().mult(5));
    this.alive = !(this.pos.x > cw || this.pos.x < 0 || this.pos.y > ch || this.pos.y < 0);
    var counts = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
        var astPos = asteroids[i].pos.clone();
        astPos.sub(this.pos); //3 impact area
        if (asteroids[i].onscreen && astPos.len() < asteroids[i].sizes[asteroids[i].level] + 10) {
            asteroids[i].hit(this.dir);
            if (counts < 5) {
                this.alive = false;
                counts++;
                //alert("the count is" + counts);
            }
            if (counts > 5) {
                this.alive = true;
                counts++;
                alert("the count is" + counts);
            }
            return counts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it not counting at all? Is it not counting in certain situations? Is it skipping numbers? Are there errors? What is your idea of "how it is supposed to count"?

Comment: Let me guess: `<Laser>.update()` always return `1`?

Comment: Tip: use `console.log` instead of `alert`. You've supplied code—which is great—but you forgot to actually ask a question in your question.

Comment: no im meaning counts++ for both of them i am going to change what the 2nd function is doing after i can get them both to work properly and keep the count

Comment: and the count is skipping numbers jumping back and forth between numbers

Comment: @HowardBeeman If you have additional information to add, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15286478/edit) to be an actual question, supplying the necessary information.

Comment: pull the `return` out where it belongs and I think the last bit of logic can reduce to something like `this.alive=(counts++>5)`and its good speed wise to set a var for looped *.length iterations

Answer (score 3):

May be you did not consider the case when counts == 5 , hence it does not execute counts++ AT ALL, when the count reaches 5. You can change the code of the if condition to

```
 if (counts<5){

            this.alive = false;
            counts++;
            //alert("the count is" + counts);
 }
 else{

             this.alive = true;
             counts++;
              alert("the count is" + counts);

 }
```

or something like that ... to consider the case when counts == 5.

**EDIT** : also place the return statement outside the for loop. Try then

**EDIT2** : also change the if statement to

`if (asteroids[i].onscreen && (astPos.len() < (asteroids[i].sizes[asteroids[i].level] + 10))) {`

gives it better readability

**EDIT3** : considering the comments below, There are two things you can try.

1. Place the return statement outside the for loop. like this

   ```
   if (counts > 5) {
                       this.alive = true;
                       counts++;
                       alert("the count is" + counts);
                   }
               }
           }
          return counts;
       }
   ```
2. Or, you can declare "counts" as a global variable and increment the "counts" in your function as you have in the comments.  and return it. In this case, the for loop will not make much sense. you may as well remove it then. try this and let us know.

Comment: i have considered that but it worn work for what i want the function to do after i can get the function to keep count right i am going to have an other statement that resets the counter to 0 after the 2nds if statement reaches a certion point

Comment: are you using the name "counts" anywhere else too? and expecting that it will contribute to the change in the "counts" of your code that you have shown (asking because, you said you have considered that). Because, as you have declared "var counts" here, it is only local to the function. and also breaks at counts == 5.

Comment: Also, you may want to place the return statement outside the for loop.

Comment: no im only using the var counts in this function of my project to try to keep track of the counter so i can manipulate weither this.alive is either true or false when i need it to be at a certain point and ohh so the counts wont keep track of the counter after if passes throw the first if statment and reaches 5??? and it wont keep track on the 2nd if statment

Comment: yes, isn't it very obvious from the code in the question. You can change it to something like in the answer i posted.

Comment: and it glitches the game by letting the laser pass through objects and not hit them at all if i put the return statement outside the loop

Comment: Also, because the "counts" is inside the for loop, the whole function **ALWAYS** returns 1 at the max, or 0. Because there is no way it can go more than that. (Refer to the edit in the answer)

Comment: yes it would be if i wasnt going to put another statement that reset the count to 0 after it reaches a certain point

Comment: the count does go past 1 and 0 it just to all numbers between 1-5 if its false and it jumps in between number 6-28 if its true i just need the count to keep a constant climb of 1 per time i use the loop

Comment: Then, maybe you are looking at the wrong function and the wrong place for the counts??, because in the code you have posted, it is a maximum of 1 for sure. .. (Also look at Edit 2)

Comment: i tryed your 2nd edit and it didnt change much but here is what i want it to do basicly beside ima change the counts numbers to high later on after i get it working

Comment: if (counts<=5){
   
   this.alive = false;
   counts++;
   alert("the count is" + counts);
   
  
   
   }
  
   
   else if(counts>5){
    
     this.alive = true;
     counts++;
     alert("the count is" + counts);
     
    }  
    else if (counts >= 20)
    {
   counts = 0;
   alert("yay i got here");
    }
    return counts;
  }
 }

Comment: but why wont count keep track

Comment: Well, as already mentioned, as soon as the for loop runs the first time, it may or may not satisfy the if conditions, and hence may or may not increment the counter. In either case. loop runs only once and returns 1 or 0.

Comment: Try the Edit 3 in the answer also.